# Imprimir corretamente um valor double utilizando ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou tendo dificuldades em imprimir um valor monetário corretamente com a distribuição de suas casas decimais, utilizei o `ToString()` usando parâmetros como **"C"**, **"F"** e **"N"**, o que precisa ser feito para deixar um valor monetário correto?

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;

namespace AtividadeRepeticao
{
    class Program2
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            double valor = 1000.50;
            Write($"Valor: {valor.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)}");
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Valor esperado
1.000,50
// Valor imprimido
100.050,00
```

Comment: Tá com erro de sintaxe `Write($"R$: {valor.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}));`, corrige isso aí.

Comment: Eu corrigi a sintaxe aqui e não apresentou esse resultado sugerido na pergunta: [resultado](https://imgur.com/a/5q6Xrdy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer um valor monetário você usar um `decimal` e não um `double`. Se quer na cultura corrente não tem porque especificar isto.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace AtividadeRepeticao {
    class Program2 {
        static void Main() {
            decimal valor = 1000.50M;
            Write($"R$: {valor}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xCcVWe). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6poRu4). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatMoney.cs).

Eu acho que este código produz um resultado mais adequado, mas se quer insistir no seu jeito e o problema é as aspas dentro de aspas então use parênteses:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace AtividadeRepeticao {
    class Program2 {
        static void Main() {
            decimal valor = 1000.50M;
            Write($"R$: {valor.ToString(("C"))}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FFdmHp). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGZ6Fk). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatMoney2.cs).